# New int by user input

Tags: c++, integer

I have a problem. I want to create an integer by user input. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char newVar;
    string newVarName;
    cout << "New Variable? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> newVar;
    if (newVar == 'y') {
        /* newVarName declares new int with the name
        of the user input (newVarName = test --> int test)*/
    } else {
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `std::map<std::string, int> user_vars;` so you can map the name of the int to the int value.

Answer (score 4):

As @Fantastic Mr Fox mentioned :

> ```
> int name_dependant_on_user_input = value_from_user
> ```
>
> This is impossible in c++, because the variable name, is a compile
> time thing. The user input happens at runtime, which is after
> compilation has completed. Something you could do, is map a string
> input to your user input, for eg.

Some other error: `String` should be `string` or `std::string`. And using `break;` while not within loop or `switch` statements will return an error. If you want to escape immidiately, you could use `exit(0);`

Otherwise, as @Eljay mentioned above, a `map<string, int>` can be used to store both the name and value of your variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char newVar;
    string newVarName;
    map<string, int> varName;
    cout << "New Variable? (y/n) : ";
    cin >> newVar;

    if (newVar == 'y') {
        cout << "Name : "; cin >> newVarName;
        cout << "Int : "; cin >> varName[newVarName];
    } else {
        exit(0);
    }

    //testing
    cout << "Test : " << newVarName << " = " << varName[newVarName];

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
New Variable? (y/n) : y
Name : var
Int : 5
Test : var = 5
```

Also, see [why `using namespace std;` is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

More info:

- `std::map` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map
- `std::string`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Answer (score 2):

In c++, you need to be aware of the common concepts of compile time and run time. So in your example:

```
// newVarName declares new int with the name of the user input
```

If you mean something like this:

```
int name_dependant_on_user_input = value_from_user
```

This is impossible in c++, because the variable name, is a compile time thing. The user input happens at runtime, which is after compilation has completed. Something you could do, is map a string input to your user input, for eg.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> user_vars;
std::string variable_name;
int variable_value;

cin >> variable_name;
cin >> variable_value;
user_vars[variable_name] = variable_value;

...

for (const auto& value_pair : user_Vars) {
    std::cout << "User value for " << value_pair.first << " is " << value_pair.second;
}
```